# Make swap space look like real RAM 12.04 server

Tags: 12.04, server

Is it possible to make swap space appear to look like real RAM, i have had a few issues where programs will only use available real RAM and not use swap. If it is possible how would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you don't want to. [SATA maxes at about 2 GB/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths#Storage) read/write speed. Whereas, [DDR3 RAM has about 16-24 GB/s transfer rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths#Dynamic_random_access_memory).

So basically, you're going to be running about 10 times slower - and that's if you have the highest speed hard drives out there (you might, but probability sides with that you don't). Also, that's [not how RAM/swap works](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-swap-what-is.html). Swap is for things that are INACTIVE. If you try to put an active process entirely in swap, you're going to have a slow time.

Comment: I think you're being very generous with regard to disk speed.  Don't forget that memory latency is measured in nanoseconds whereas disk latemcy may be measured in milliseconds (1 million times as long) - a single disk access may take 100,000 to 1,000,000 times the amount of time as a single memory access.  A computer that treated disk as memory would never get anything done.  It's why memory swapped to disk MUST be swapped back to RAM before it can be used again as RAM, else it'd be 100,000 to 1,000,000 times slower on a per memory access basis.